# A group acts on a disk

Tags: group-theory, geometry

Let $G$ be a group, it acts continuously on a disk $\mathbb{D}$, $g$ is a non-trivial central element of $G$. The set of fixed points of $g$ is $\partial\mathbb{D}$, I want to prove that for $h\in G$, $x$ is a fixed point of $h$, then $\{g^n(x)\}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ accumulate on $\partial\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: This sounds quite plausible. Is this a statement you read somewhere?

Comment: [link](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/groupesengendres.pdf) P168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was proven by Brouwer in 1912 (see lemma on page 234 [her](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ojm/1200688070)) that for every $p$ in $D$, the sequence $g^n(p)$ has all its accumulation points in the boundary circle $\partial D$. Note that Brouwer was considering fixed-point free homeomorphisms $f$ of $R^2$, and he proved that every sequence  $f^n(x)$, $x\in R^2$, diverges to infinity.

Comment: How to prove that lemma? I can't find the reference [1] in that book.

Comment: The reference is L.E. Brouwer, "Beweis des ebenen Translationssatzes", Math. Ann. 72 (1912) 37-54. It is in German, but it might have been translated to English in L. E. J. Brouwer collected works: Geometry, analysis, topology and mechanics, Volume 2, 1976.